# WSO2 CEP 3.1.0 + WSO2 MB 3.1.0 Integration (Stream Issue)

Tags: wso2, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker, wso2-cep

I've been following this [sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Using+WSO2+MB+as+A+JMS+Broker+for+WSO2+CEP+Server) of `Using WSO2 MB as A JMS Broker for WSO2 CEP Server` from the official `WSO2 MB` documentation. Since this doc doesn't support the latest version of CEP, tried integrating the `MB` with the `CEP 3.1.0`.

According to the given steps, to my knowledge the stream "org.wso2.sample.stock.quote.basic:1.0.0" should be automatically generated and appear on the Event Streams section once the CEP and MB is up and running. Am I heading in the right direction or should I create my own stream and move forward with the other steps? Did all the configuration changes according to the doc but then the stream ain't appearing on the Event Stream section.

Where could I have gone wrong ? Checked out this [ticket](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION-1354) as well but no use. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: By the way I tried this on Windows, should I be trying this on Linux ?

Comment: Can you try out with latest CEP release? 4.0.0 ot=r 4.1.0

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne Yup tried it with the latest one as well, din work. As per the doc the CEP shoule be having `Event Builder`, but then the latest one doesn't have.

Comment: From CEP 4.0.0 onwards we do not have a concept of event builders but event receivers and publishers.Please refer [https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Architecture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per the [Link](http://sajithr.blogspot.com/2014/04/sample-on-using-wso2-mb-with-wso2-cep.html) you need to start the cep server in sample mode pointing to sample number 0002. Please run ./wso2cep-samples.sh -sn 0002 -DportOffset=1 -Dqpid.dest_syntax=BUR (portoffset to correct value). Then mentioned stream will be deployed.

cheers.

Comment: I have started the cep 3.1.0 with above command and i could see the stream org.wso2.sample.stock.quote.basic:1.0.0. Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: You're using the same version of MB as well? Nop i'm not getting any errors in the log. You tried it on Win ??

Comment: I only checked why the stream is not coming up. I have not setup the MB. I checked on a linux environment. Can you tell me the command you used to start in sample mode.

Comment: Could we discuss it here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109617/cep-and-mb-integration

Comment: It should be wso2cep-samples.bat -sn 0002 -DportOffset=1 -Dqpid.dest_syntax=BURL